# Third and Second person in one sentence referring to "you"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say: "You are the one who's saying that he can't understand what he wrote, therefore I can't help you."? How understandable it is? A friend and I were arguing about this.

Comment: Please clearly state which part exactly you are arguing about, and for what reason. Otherwise this will be closed as a proofreading request. Thank you.

Comment: It's comprehensible, but it would be far more idiomatic to say "you" in place of "he" in both cases.

Comment: It's ambiguous -- unclear whether the two "he"s refer to the same person.

Comment: Compare it to a conversion of a teacher with a parent about the latter's ward. It makes complete sense. You (the parent) are the one who is saying that he (his son) can't understand what he wrote; therefore I (the teacher) cannot help you (the parent).

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence "he" refers to "the one". "You" are the noun-phrase beginning "one..." and ending " ...what he wrote". You could replace that noun phrase with a single noun, such as "fool" as in: "You are the fool, therefore I can't help you".

It is perfectly grammatical, therefore.

If you need to ask whether it is understandable, then maybe it isn't; what is understandable is in the mind of the reader, not of the writer. It is certainly a convoluted way of expressing a simple, if insulting, thought.

Comment: You're not understandable.

Comment: @HotLicks, what about the answer is not understandable? The answer says that the sentence is technically correct, because the antecedent of *he* is *one*, but may nevertheless be difficult to understand.